# Getting variable from AsyncStorage and putting into Axios

Tags: react-native

I have been trying to get a variable from AsyncStorage and then put it into an Axios get request. The problem is that the variable is not updating to the data that is retrieved from AsyncStorage. How do I make it do that?

Here is my code:

```
const [sku, setSku] = useState('')

  const STORAGE_KEY_SKU = '@save_sku'

  const readSku = async () => {
    try {
      const selectedSku = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY_SKU)

      if (selectedSku !== null) {
        setSku(selectedSku)
      }
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Failed to fetch the data from storage')
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    readSku()
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get(`https://api.vexdb.io/v1/get_matches?sku=${sku}`)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        //console.log("defaultApp -> data", data)
        setData(data.result)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, []);
```

Im trying to put get the sku variable from the state from AsyncStorage, but the ${sku} in the axios get request link is not working, the sku is blank in that statement.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: nvm, fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

```
useFocusEffect(() => {   
      readSku()
    }, []);
```

```
const STORAGE_KEY_SKU = '@save_sku'

// to get the session username from localstorage
  const readSku = async () => {
    try {
      const selectedSku = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY_SKU)
      if (selectedSku !== null) {
        setSku(selectedSku)
       }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

```
const setSku = async (selectedSku) => {
       Axios.get(`https://api.vexdb.io/v1/get_matches?sku=${selectedSku}`)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        //console.log("defaultApp -> data", data)
        setData(data.result)
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
}
```